# Obtain real-time heart rate/ecg from Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, watch, watchos, heartrate

is it possible to obtain the heart rate (or even the raw ecg data) from the Apple Watch in real time? If yes, what is the 'update frequency'? I.e. does the watch send the data every 100ms, every second, every 10 seconds? I'd need the data only for a short period (1-2mins), but with the highest possible update frequency. I assume the data must be captured and processed at a very high rate since the heart rate variability is computed from it, but I am wondering if I as a developer have access to the full raw data at full time resolution.

Thanks a lot!

PS: there are a few related posts on this topic, but they are quite old and not 100% what I need